# How Mule Standalone actually works?

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule, and I am trying to understand the difference between the mule standalone vs embedded. I have read of topics regarding this but I was not able to answer one question. How the Mule standalone actually work? how it handles web services? does it have an application server's functionality? does it have an embedded or bundled app server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mule Standalone Server is a proprietary application server that hosts Mule-specific applications [packaged in a specific format](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Application+Format).

Alternatively, Mule can be embedded in another application (like a JavaEE Web Application)  very much like Spring Web Flow can be embedded: add Maven dependencies and tie Mule to the container via a bootstrap class (like a Servlet Context Listener for JavaEE Web Applications).

Independently of the deployment scenario (standalone or embedded), a Mule application can do many things including exposing web services.

Comment: But the standalone deployment will not limit any JAVA code that may need to be written within the scope of the ESB. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Absolutely, you can deploy custom Java code as part of your Mule application on the Standalone server.